# How would one rewrite this raw query in knexjs?

Tags: knex.js

I'm trying to rewrite the following in knex query builder js.

Does anyone know how to do that?

```js
knex.raw(
    /* sql */ `
      UPDATE "product-products_fields" SET value = ?
      WHERE productid = ?
      AND fieldid = (SELECT fieldid FROM "product-fields" WHERE field = ?)`,
   [value, productId, field],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 query:

```
const firstQuery = await knex("product-fields")
.where("field", field)
.select("fieldid")

const secondQuery = await knex("product-products_fields")
.update("value", value)
.where("productid", productId)
.andWhere("fieldid", firstQuery)
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Will this result in one query to the DB or two?

Comment: As you can see, there will be 2. `firstQuery` will get one data, and then, `secondQuery` will take that data, and this will be second query. Actually, your `sql` query is also consists of 2 parts - `update` and `select`

Comment: Does your example requires 2 roundtriips or just 1 like mine?